# How can I generate a list of specific recommended extensions for my `.code-workspace`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.78.2 on macOS 10.13.6 and trying to generate an `extensions.json` file. In my `~/dev/` directory, there are three folders: `java`, `py`, and `ws`. I launched Visual Studio Code (VSCode) and selected the 'New Window' command from the 'File' menu.
In the new VSCode window, I clicked on 'Open Folder' from the 'File' menu and chose to open the `~/dev/py` directory. I then saved the workspace in the `~/dev/ws` directory.

here are the entire contents of my `py.code-workspace`

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "../py"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "extensions": {
        "recommendations": ["ms-python.python"]
    }
}
```

I already have an `extensions.json` file in my `~/.vscode` directory that contains hundreds of extensions for all workspaces. However, for my `py.code-workspace`, I would like to generate a new `extensions.json` file that contains only Python-related extensions. To achieve this, I uninstalled the `python` extension from VSCode and installed it in the VSCode window that is associated with my `py.code-workspace`. Despite these steps, neither the `~/dev/py` directory nor the `py.code-workspace` contains an `extensions.json` file. How can I generate an `extensions.json` file that contains only Python-related extensions for my `py.code-workspace`?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Extensions View, and for each extension that you want to be recommended, click the gear icon in the extension's entry in the Extension View, click the action that says "Add to Workspace Recommendations", and then select a scope for the recommendation- either at a per-workspace root level, or for the whole multi-root workspace (which seems to be what you want here- this option is the one labelled "Workspace").

Side-note: you may also be interested in [Profile Templates](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_profile-templates).